# Adding new Android and iOS apps on Fabric from command line script

Tags: android, ios, twitter-fabric, google-fabric

I have just automated the process of new targets/flavors creation for my Android and iOS projects. For Android I use a bash script to add new flavor to Android app and then build and sign the app. For iOS I use a script which builds a target and "dynamically" sets all of the necessary parameters and then archives the app end exports to the .ipa file.

I know how to add a new build to the app "project" which already exists on Fabric, but I haven't found any way to upload completely new flavor/target for the first time from command line/script. Is there any way/hack to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Mike from Fabric here.

There isn't a hack or workaround for this currently. We need both a build and run from the app in order to activate the app within the Fabric dashboard.

Comment: Hi! Worth mentioning, one interesting way around this is using Fastlane to build and run your app locally.